# Using scrapy sharp with login

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, web-scraping, scrapysharp

I have created one simple windows app using c# windows forms and scrapysharp library.I have parsed data without problem. But now I need to parse data from another page which requires login.
The problem is I dont know how to save cookies in this simulated browser while using this libray.

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection(); 

Browser.UseDefaultCookiesParser = true; WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("blackboard.coursesites.com/")); PageWebForm 

form = PageResult.FindForm("login"); 
form["user_id"] = "test"; 
form["password"] = "test"; 
form.Method = HttpVerb.Post; 
WebPage resultsPage = form.Submit(); 
WebPage page = resultsPage;
```

When i submit form with username and password, it does not remember my session

Comment: Can you provide what research you have done so far about this topic? What code have you tried so far? What were the results?

Comment: CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();

Browser.UseDefaultCookiesParser = true;            
WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("https://blackboard.coursesites.com/"));
PageWebForm form = PageResult.FindForm("login");
form["user_id"] = "***";
form["password"] = "***";
form.Method = HttpVerb.Post;
            
WebPage resultsPage = form.Submit();

WebPage page = resultsPage;

When i submit form with username and password, it does not remember my session

Comment: Please add this to your **question post**, not as a comment.